# higher or lower card game in python

Tags: python

I need to write some code which shows a random single number/card from 1-12, the player then guesses whether the next card will be higher or lower than the first card/number. (play your cards right british game) if they guess right they get another go, if they guess wrong (they say higher or lower and it's the opposite) they lose and the game ends. if they guess four in a row right they win.

I have a very rough idea of how to go about this.

Could you please lend a hand?

```
import random

guessesTaken = 0 

print('Hello! I am going to show you a card, guess whether the next card is higher or lower, get four in a row to win!')


number = random.randint(1, 12)
number1 = random.randint(1, 12)
number2 = random.randint(1, 12)
number3 = random.randint(1, 12)
number4 = random.randint(1, 12)

#five variables for five cards, all random cards between 1 and 12

print('Well I am thinking of a card between 1 and 12, the first number is:')
print (number) #shows them first card

while guessesTaken < 5: #limit number of guesses to make game less than 4 to win?
    print('Take a guess, is the next card higher or lower? Please enter a number from 1 to 12.') 
    guess = input()
    guess = str(guess) # limit input to "h" or "l"?

    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1 #increment guesses taken

    if guess = h and guess !> number1:
    print ("you lose")
        break

    if guess =l and guess !< number1:
        print('you lose')

    if guess = h and guess !< number1:
    print ("well done")
        #ask about next card

    if guess =l and guess !> number1:
        print('well done')
        #ask about next card


    if guess == number1:
        print ('you lose it was neither higher nor lower')
        break

    #basically I know the middle comparison for values higher or lower for the four cards can be done with a loop, just not sure how, very new to this.
```

second version (working sort of)

```
import random

guessesTaken = 0 

print('Hello! I am going to show you a card, guess whether the next card is higher or lower, get four in a row to win!')

number = random.randint(1, 12)

#five variables for five cards, all random cards between 1 and 12

print('Well I am thinking of a card between 1 and 12, the first number is:')
print (number) #shows them first card

guess = input('Take a guess, is the next card higher or lower? Please enter either "h" or "l".')

while guessesTaken <= 4: #limit number of guesses to make game less than 4 to win?

    if guessesTaken == 4:
        print("You win")
        break
    else:
        nextnumber = random.randint(1,12)
        print(nextnumber)

        if guess == "h" and nextnumber <= number:
            print ("you lose")
            break
        elif guess == "l" and nextnumber >= number:
            print ("you lose")
            break
        else:
            guess = input("the card was" + str(nextnumber) + "is the next card higher or lower?")

        guessesTaken += 1 #increment guesses taken
        number = nextnumber
```

Comment: "I have a very rough idea..."  Please, show some code of your rough idea.

Comment: Stack Overflow is built around a very specific question-answer format. If you want to get help here, you need to ask a specific question you need answered. Otherwise, you're trying to have a conversation, which Stack Overflow is specifically designed to reject.

Comment: Hi sorry, didn't mean to seem as though I am asking for people to do all the work, I genuinely am new to python. I have put my effort above, basic as it is.

Comment: OK to reply to the second comment, my question is, how do i go about building a loop to iterate through the game making a comparison each turn until the player loses or wins based on the format above. Also apologies this is my first post, I will be more specific in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, lets make your code a little more pythonic...

```
import random

DECK_SIZE = 5

# See that it generates 5 unique random number from 1 to 12 
# (not including 13) thus simulating a deck of cards, 
# where cards cannot repeat. We add a None in the end to
# indicate end of deck
deck = random.sample(range(1, 13), DECK_SIZE) + [None]

# use of the zip method to create pairs of cards to compare 
# (the final card will be a None, so we can see when cards ended)
for card,next_card in zip(deck[:-1],deck[1:]):
    if next_card == None: # End of deck, user won the game
        print("You won")
        break

    # we calculate the expected correct guess 
    # based on the pair of cards
    correct_guess = "h" if next_card > card else "l"

    # We get the user input
    guess = input("card is {card} is next h or l? ".format(card=card))

    # We verify if user input is the expected correct guess
    if guess != correct_guess:
        print("You lost, card was {next_card}".format(next_card=next_card))
        break
```

I hope you can improve your python skills by studying this code and making changes to fulfill your needs. It uses a few python idiosyncrasies that may help you get some knowledge.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I think I got off on the wrong foot with those above, I am not a student trying to do their homework, I have agreed to teach some python to students and they had this task, I did C programming over 8 years ago and nothing since, I was genuinely struggling with comparing the guess with an input of "h" and "l" whilst also comparing if it was higher or lower. Also kept tripping up when using && and i++ etc. I just needed some help with the logic. I did eventually get there but yours is far better and easier to understand than the while I came up with.